# Сохранение данных с использованием forms.form

Tags: python, django, form

Здравствуйте.
Прошу помочь в одном вопросе. Хочу сделать сохранение данных в форме обратной связи, используя класс **forms.form**, для управления выводом html кода формы.
В документации есть примеры сохранения данных только с использованием **ModelForm** у которого есть метод **save()**, когда django создает объект по форме самостоятельно. У **forms.form** нет этого метода, и если я правильно понял, нужно создать сначала объект модели, а потом сохранить его, используя метод **save()**. Подскажите, как это правильно сделать. Спасибо.

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from models import Contacts

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Contacts

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254)
    message = forms.CharField(
        max_length=2000,
        widget=forms.Textarea(),
        help_text='Write here your message!'
    )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
        name = cleaned_data.get('name')
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        message = cleaned_data.get('message')
        if not name and not email and not message:
            raise forms.ValidationError('You have to write something!')
```

**views.py**

```
def addcontact(request):
    if request.POST:
        form_c = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form_c.is_valid():
            f.save() # не работает т.к. у ContactForm нет этого метода
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contacts/thanks/')
    else:
        form_c = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'contacts.html', {'form_c': form_c})
```

Comment: Точно так же, как и создание-сохранение модели без формы

Comment: Т.е. нужно парсить request?

Comment: Зачем парсить? Форма уже сама всё распарсила, просто доставайте данные из неё. Как работать с формами и читать её поля — всё это есть в документации Django

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 1):

**views.py**

```
def addcontact(request):
if request.POST:
    form_c = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form_c.is_valid():
        f = Contacts(
            contacts_name=form_c.cleaned_data['name'],
            contacts_email=form_c.cleaned_data['email'],
            contacts_message=form_c.cleaned_data['message'])
        f.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contacts/thanks/')
else:
    form_c = ContactForm()
return render(request, 'contacts.html', {'form_c': form_c})
```